# The design of a query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT u.username,
       r.position,
       r.score,
       r.winner,
       t.team
FROM   ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_ROUNDS." r
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u
         ON u.id = r.winner
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." pl
         ON pl.userid = r.winner
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TEAMS." t
         ON t.id = pl.team
WHERE  pl.tourid = '$tour_id' && r.tourid = '$tour_id' && r.round = '$i'
ORDER  BY r.position
```

I have one problem with this query. The `WHERE pl.tourid = '$tour_id'` is reliant on the `LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." pl ON pl.userid = r.winner`. As it's a left join, how can I make that `WHERE` only function if the `LEFT JOIN` does?

Can't think of a solution!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you only want rows with no matching winner, or where the winner has the specified tourid. In this case, you would use:

```
WHERE (pl.tourid IS NULL OR pl.tourid = '$tour_id')
```

Alternatively, if you only want to link to the player if (s)he has the right tourid, then add it to the `ON` clause:

```
ON pl.userid = r.winner AND pl.tourid = '$tour_id'
```

The results will be different, either might be what you are looking for.

Comment: The second ON AND is what worked for me. I wasn't aware you could do this. Very helpful. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username,
       r.position,
       r.score,
       r.winner,
       t.team
FROM   ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_ROUNDS." r
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u
         ON u.id = r.winner
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." pl
         ON pl.userid = r.winner
         AND pl.tourid = '$tour_id'
         AND r.tourid = '$tour_id'
         AND r.round = '$i'
       LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TEAMS." t
         ON t.id = pl.team
ORDER  BY r.position
```